ERROR (0x8007000e) in the DataTransferService.log and no per-machine targetted applications visible in Software Center
I have a SCCM (5.00.9122.1000) test environment with 3 HyperV clients (Windows 10 22H2).
My issue is that in the Software Center, only the per-user available applications are visible and the per-system applications are not visible. Also, there are no Updates available. It seems that the per-system application policies are not downloaded and applied.
I see that the policies are not downloaded correctly:
From the DataTransferService.log (on the client)
DTSJob({1B9B3AF9-2286-4770-A226-D4A52831D8DA}): Job has completed: Status : ERROR (0x8007000e), Start time : 05/30/2024 14:55:24, Completion time : 05/30/2024 14:55:24, Elapsed time : 0 seconds

When I do a search on 8007000e, I see a lot about disk space. The clients have at least 50Gb of free space. That should not be an issue. Memory of each HyperV VM is 4096Mb.
From the PolicyAgent.log:

Raising event:
instance of CCM_PolicyAgent_PolicyDownloadFailed
{
    ClientID = "GUID:054D06E7-A013-4B2F-9C3A-C1B2638F5D39";
    DateTime = "20240530125525.881000+000";
    DownloadErrorInfo = 
instance of CCM_BitsDownloadMethod_ErrorInfo
{
    ErrorCode = 2147942414;
    ErrorMessage = "Error downloading data.";
};
    DownloadMethod = "BITS";
    DownloadSource = "http://<mp>/SMS_MP/.sms_pol?{ca0c49fe-00cb-4183-b49a-7bbb0c326645}.3341_00";
    PolicyNamespace = "\\\\.\\ROOT\\ccm\\policy\\machine\\requestedconfig";
    PolicyPath = "CCM_Policy_Policy5.PolicyID=\"{ca0c49fe-00cb-4183-b49a-7bbb0c326645}\",PolicyVersion=\"3341.00\",PolicySource=\"SMS:TST\"";
    ProcessID = 6616;
    ThreadID = 1696;
};

From PolicyEvaluator.log

No errors

From C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex240529.log

$Log = Get-Content -Path "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex240529.log"
$Log | ForEach-Object {$_} | Where {($_ -match '/ccm_system_windowsauth') -and ($_ -match ' ccmhttp ')}

    2024-05-28 22:16:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 118
2024-05-28 22:16:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test43 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4408 47
2024-05-28 22:19:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 0
2024-05-28 22:19:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test6 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 13670 19
2024-05-28 22:27:36 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.101 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 1
2024-05-28 22:27:36 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test7 5.6.6.101 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4391 14
2024-05-28 22:48:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 0
2024-05-28 22:48:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test43 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4408 24
2024-05-28 22:58:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 0
2024-05-28 22:58:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test6 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4396 21
2024-05-28 23:19:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 0
2024-05-28 23:19:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test43 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4408 109
2024-05-28 23:51:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 80
2024-05-28 23:51:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test6 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4396 27
2024-05-28 23:56:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 0
2024-05-28 23:56:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test43 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4408 17
2024-05-29 00:48:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 77
2024-05-29 00:48:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test6 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4396 27
2024-05-29 00:53:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 0
2024-05-29 00:53:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test43 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4408 14
2024-05-29 01:24:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 78
2024-05-29 01:24:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test6 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4396 115
2024-05-29 01:28:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 0
2024-05-29 01:28:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test43 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4408 15
2024-05-29 02:03:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 70
2024-05-29 02:03:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test6 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4396 25
2024-05-29 02:21:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 1
2024-05-29 02:21:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test43 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4408 34
2024-05-29 02:56:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 73
2024-05-29 02:56:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test6 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4396 29
2024-05-29 03:11:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 0
2024-05-29 03:11:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test43 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4408 30
2024-05-29 03:47:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 68
2024-05-29 03:47:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test43 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4408 24
2024-05-29 03:53:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 0
2024-05-29 03:53:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test6 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4396 15
2024-05-29 04:27:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 75
2024-05-29 04:27:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test43 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4408 28
2024-05-29 04:29:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 1
2024-05-29 04:29:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test6 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4396 12
2024-05-29 05:00:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 82
2024-05-29 05:00:49 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test6 5.6.6.102 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4396 90
2024-05-29 05:14:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 8
2024-05-29 05:14:22 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test43 5.6.6.103 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 4408 205
2024-05-29 16:02:28 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 - 5.6.6.101 ccmhttp - 401 2 5 1510 117
2024-05-29 16:02:28 5.6.6.2 CCM_POST /ccm_system_windowsauth/request - 80 DEMO\Test7 5.6.6.101 ccmhttp - 200 0 0 7132 202

If I go to a client, open Edge and enter the URL http://<mp>/SMS_MP/.sms_pol?{ca0c49fe-00cb-4183-b49a-7bbb0c326645}.3341_00 (where  has been changed to the URL of the mp) information is shown in Edge.
To avoid certificate-issues, I have set up the following:

Distribution Point -> tab [Communication] -> HTTP has been selected, with the option to [Allow clients to connect anonymously] selected.
Distribution Point -> tab [Communication] -> Create self-siged certificate -> expiration date: 09/23/2120
Management Point -> tab [General] -> Client connections HTTP
Under Site Configuration -> Sites -> SiteName -> tab [Communication Security] -> HTTPS or HTTP has been selected with the option [Use Configuration Manager-generated certificates for HTTP site systems] unselected.

My question is what I can do to resolve the error Job has completed: Status : ERROR (0x8007000e) in the DataTransferService.log
Any help is appreciated.
Edit: 2024-06-01: Better description of the issue and troubleshooting steps.
$Computer          = "vm01-w10-22h2"
$Class             = "CCM_Policy_Policy"
$Namespace         = "ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig"
$ArrayWithPolicies = @()

$WMIDetails= @{ComputerName = $Computer
               Class        = $Class
               Namespace    = $Namespace}

Clear-Host
Write-Host "Class [$Class] on namespace [$Namespace] on computer [$Computer]"


$States    = Get-WmiObject @WMIDetails | Select-Object -Property PolicyState -Unique
ForEach ($State in $States)
 {
  $Policy           = (Get-WmiObject @WMIDetails -Filter "PolicyState = '$($State.PolicyState)'") 
  $PolicyCategories = $Policy | Select-Object -Property PolicyCategory -Unique
  ForEach ($PolicyCategory in $PolicyCategories)
   {
    $PolicyCategoriesDetailed = ($Policy | Where-Object {$_.PolicyCategory -eq $($PolicyCategory.PolicyCategory)})
    $Record = [Ordered]@{"Computer"      = $Computer
                         "Class"         = $Class
                         "Namespace"     = $Namespace
                         "PolicyState"   = $($State.PolicyState)
                         "PolicyCategory"= $($PolicyCategory.PolicyCategory)
                         "Count"         = $(($PolicyCategoriesDetailed | Measure-Object).Count)}
    $ArrayWithPolicies += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Record
   }
 }

 $ArrayWithPolicies | Format-Table

Class [CCM_Policy_Policy] on namespace [ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig] on computer [vm01-w10-22h2]

Computer      Class             Namespace                               PolicyState     PolicyCategory           Count
--------      -----             ---------                               -----------     --------------           -----
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig DownloadStarted VersionInfo                 72
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig DownloadStarted CIPolicyAssignment           1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig DownloadStarted ApplicationDeployment       13
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig DownloadStarted SoftwareUpdateDeployment    16
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig DownloadStarted CIAssociation                9
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig DownloadStarted UpdateSource                 2
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig DownloadStarted ClientServicing              1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig DownloadStarted                              2
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig DownloadStarted SoftwareDistribution         2
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig DownloadStarted MachineSettings              1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active                                      11
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          NAAConfig                    1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          SuperPeerConfig              1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          NetworkSettingsConfig        1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          RebootSettingsConfig         1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          CollectionSettings           1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          UserConfig                   1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          SoftUpdConfig                1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          EditionUpgradeConfig         1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          AppManClientConfig           1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          FEPConfig                    1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          SiteRoleSettingsConfig       1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          ClientResourcesConfig        1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          RootCACertConfig             1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          CloudConfig                  1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          SoftDistConfig               1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          BigGreenButtonConfig         1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          EventActivity                2
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          SoftwareCenterConfig         2
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          MachineConfig                1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          WindowsAnalyticsConfig       1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          MulticastConfig              1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          ClientConfig                 1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          ThirdPartyUpdatesConfig      1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          CoMgmtSettingsConfig         1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          WindowsDOConfig              1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          AntimalwareConfig            1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          PeerPxeConfig                1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig Active          SCEPSettingsConfig           1
vm01-w10-22h2 CCM_Policy_Policy ROOT\ccm\policy\machine\requestedconfig DownloadPending ApplicationDeployment       12

